# Creating alias failing in bashrc using function method

Tags: function, bourne-shell

I am trying to create alias in `bashrc` using function method as I need to pass argument while executing.

## Here i have created alias.

```
login-lnx1 () { 'ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p "$1" -l username lnx2'; }
```

## Here is output after execution.

```
bash-3.2$ login-lnx1 3001
bash: ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p "$1" -l username lnx2: No such file or directory
```

Comment: As @xhienne says in his answer, functions are not aliases, so there isn't a "function method" to create an alias.  You either create a function or an alias, they're different things.

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the single quotes in your *function* (this is not an alias):

```
login-lnx1 () { ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p "$1" -l username lnx2; }
```